Show Calibri font in Rails PDF
I am generating a PDF inside my rails app and want to use calibri font but it doesnt'work.

I downloaded the file
Created a folder /fonts in /assets
I put the font in that folder as calibri.ttf
changed the application.rb to include config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
Put //= link_tree ../fonts in manifest.js according to some tip in the internet
Changed newsletter.scss to include:

@font-face {
  font-family: "NL Calibri";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: block;
  src: font-url("calibri.ttf") format('truetype');
}


Rebooted the server after rails assets:precompile
Generating the Newsletter via wicked PDF inside the app

Problem
Trying to do inline font-family changes via style changes: font-family: 'NL Calibri' to the elements but the font doesn't change on the newsletter.

Not 100% sure if your problem is the same with what I had before. Mine was because of the font-face file path and the format. This solution worked for me.
https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/334#issuecomment-56982265

@Thang tried to follow this instructions but didnt help. Do I have to load fonts in header of HTML page somehow? The newsletter has its own layout namely '''newsletter.html.erb'''

how can change the font for the whole newsletter layout/page? This would be cool to continue

I added Test but still not applying the new font type

Can you check if the newletter.scss is loaded properly into the wicked_pdf? By adding a special styling like:
p { background-color: yellow; }

@KJ what Do you mean? Instead of
{font-family: "NL Calibri";}
write
{font-family: NL Calibri;}
so without quotation marks?
Thang will try later an report back. Good idea. Thought about something similar already.

@Thang I finally had time to do the check and your guess is right! The style seems to be not loaded. Potentially the head statement in the application.html.erb is wrong. It states: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'frontend', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>. I am not an expert and didn't program this but since there is a frontend.scss I assume this has to be renamed/added to newsletter since there is the newsletter.scss

It sounds to me that you are not very familiar with Rails. The way Rails render pdf with wicked_pdf is similar with the way it render a view, you can specify the template, the layout for just PDF printing. So changing frontend.scss to newsletter.scss may not be a good idea.

I am rather a back end guy! Not my code base :-) I will add something in front_end and will check if it works. Thanks @Thang
